# Regular expressions and russian symbols in Django

Tags: python, django, regex

I have the one url like this

`url(ur'^gradebook/(?P<group>[\w\-А-Яа-я])$', some_view, name='some_view')`

and I expect it to process a request like

`../gradebook/group='Ф-12б'`

but I get an error and the server crashes.

Please help me figure out the Russian symbols

Comment: The `group='...'` does not match with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The `group='…'` part is more a problem, since the equation sign `=` is not part of the character group.

Furthermore you should match *multiple* characters:

```
#                    quantifier  ↓
url(ur'^gradebook/(?P[\w\-А-Яа-я]+)$', some_view, name='some_view')
```

then this can match a URL:

```
/gradebook/Ф-12б
```

but if you want to match the group='…' as well, you should include the `=` and the `'` character:

```
#             extra characters  ↓↓
url(ur"^gradebook/(?P[\w\-А-Яа-я'=]+)$", some_view, name='some_view')
```

Then you can match with:

```
/gradebook/group='Ф-12б'
```

although that might accept too much, since it can also accept `f'q'a=gr=f` for example.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I didn't notice the missing <group>. Now I have corrected it. And your version also does not work for me, it seems that django swears at Russian characters

Comment: @jecloy: well I've tested the regular expression locally, and it worked. But you can not simply pass quotes to the URL, these are *percent encoded*.